# MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT blocking audio from call

Tags: android, audio, record, android-mediarecorder

I am working on an application that records my own voice (using `AudioSource.MIC` or `AudioSource.DEFAULT`) when a call is made or received, using MediaRecorder. The problem that I'm having is that, whenever the microphone starts recording, I can no longer hear anything from the call. As soon as I remove the application, I can hear everything perfectly.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to listen to my call normally, while recording my voice with the microphone?

PS: I'm not asking about `AudioSource.VOICE_CALL` or any of those things which I know are blocked and all that. Please help me!

Comment: _"VOICE_CALL or any of those things which I know are blocked"_ What do you mean by that they _"are blocked"_? Recording voice calls using the `VOICE_CALL` AudioSource works fine on most of the devices I've worked with. Regarding your problem; if starting a recording during a voice call causes the voice call audio to disappear that really sounds like a bug in your device's audio implementation. Which device are you testing this on?

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>





recorder.reset();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
         //passing recorded file's path    
        recorder.setOutputFile(recording.getAbsolutePath()); 

        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain why you think this would solve the OP's problem?